# Loading tooltip message dynamically from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Consider the fiddle given, where the tooltip message is passed from the html. What changes should be made if I want to pass the tooltip message from JavaScript or jQuery?

```
<span class="field-tip">
Hover the text.
<span class="tip-content">tooltip message</span>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dasettan/o4vp56f7/

Answer (score 1):

you just need to change text inside of your span by javascript/jquery

```
$("span.tip-content").text("new tooltip")
```

for better give your span a id and than change text inside it,otherwise if you have multiple span with tool-tip all will update

do something like

```
 <span class="tip-content" id="myspan">tooltip message</span>

  $("#myspan").text("new tooltip")
```

**[here the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o4vp56f7/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript and add id to tip-content then call this:

```
document.getElementById("tip-content").innerHTML = "new value";
```

or using jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("span.tip-content").html("new value");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
document.querySelector(".field-tip").addEventListener("mouseover", function (event) {
      document.querySelector(".tip-content").innerHTML = "My new tooltip message";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the content of the tooltip element which is simple.
If you wanted to do it repeatedly and make it work across multiple tooltips you could make a function,something like this:

```
function customMessage(ele,message) {
    var main = document.querySelector(ele),
       tooltip = main.children[0];
    main.addEventListener('mouseover',function() {
        tooltip.innerHTML = message;
    })
}
```

Make the first argument the element to be hovered and have the second be the message to be displayed in the tooltip

```
customMessage('.field-tip',"random message");
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/wtbr982g/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Following code will show tool tip when mouse is over and when you out of the text message will be changed to original one.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $( "span.field-tip" ).hover(function() {
    //Print message when mouse in
    $("span.tip-content").html("Tool tip message");
}, function() {
    //Print message when mouse out
    $("span.tip-content").html("Empty Tool tip Message");
  });
});

</script>
```